# Adding accessibility identifiers to VStack applied on all its internal views

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xctest

In XCTest, if I add accessibility identifiers to a VStack, then all its internal views are applied with the same identifiers, which I don't want.

For instance, below VStack acts as a custom button. If I apply identifier to it, View1 and View2 will have the same identifier.

```
           VStack { // identifier a
             View1  // identifier b
             View2  // identifier c
           }
           .accessibility(addTraits: .isButton)
           .accessibilityIdentifier("\(text)-btn-\(state == .disabled || state == .loading ? "disabled" : "active")")
```

By googling, I found below thread in Apple forum, it advices to use `accessibilityElement`  but then the op prove it will cause memory leak.

[SwiftUI: Adding accessibility identifiers to VStack](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/671189)

Comment: Tagging question: Is this related to XCTest? If you're trying to solve a testing problem using accessibility identifiers, it might be helpful to know.

Comment: Yes, I want to define identifiers for some custom views because they don't have identifiers in XCTest.

Comment: So this is for UI testing, then? If you can access the correct view, what do you intend to do with it?

Comment: Assert if the view is exist in XCTest, because some views or sub-views inside doesn't have text, for instance a circle image, so I need manually add identifier on them in case they could be found in XCTest.